# Rust: key/value types for input/output impl methods

Tags: rust

I am trying to defined input/output types for Rust impl methods. And I want that each module stores its own types:

```
.
├── module1
│   ├── do_thing_a.rs
│   └── interfaces
│       ├── do_thing_a_input.rs
│       └── do_thing_a_output.rs
└── module2
    ├── do_thing_b.rs
    └── interfaces
        └── do_thing_b_output.rs
```

in TypeScript I would write this

```
.
├── module1
│   ├── DoThingA.ts
│   └── interfaces
│       ├── IDoThingAInput.ts
│       └── IDoThingAOutput.ts
└── module2
    ├── DoThingB.ts
    └── interfaces
        └── IDoThingBOutput.ts
```

```js
// module1/interfaces/IDoThingAInput.ts
interface IDoThingAInput{
    value: number
}
// module1/interfaces/IDoThingAOutput.ts
interface IDoThingAOutput {
    value: boolean
}

// module1/DoThingA.ts
class DoThingA {
    execute(input: IDoThingAInput): IDoThingAOutput {
        return input.value === 1 ? { value: true }: { value: false };
    }
}

// module2/interfaces/IDoThingBOutput.ts
interface IDoThingBOutput {
    value: boolean
}

// module1/DoThingB.ts
class DoThingB {
    execute(): IDoThingBOutput {
        const object1 = new DoThingA();
        const isOk = object1.execute({value :1});

        return isOk
    }
}

const doThingB = new DoThingB();
const result = doThingB.execute();
console.log(result.value);
```

Here is its [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFsHsBMFcBsCmBGYBLAdgF0QJwGYCGAxogM7ACSAIpACoAWmA5gIKUYAOsWAdFmQBQmHARKJQNekwxsO3LAG9BoVaABuheLEQAuUBljgARnkEBfQSAgwEKdNjxFSFKYxasA8jwX8hIp3FJWndZLx8eUGU1DS0dfWNISCRCDAtBKzAoOCRUEJk2P0FieEIyMlB8jyiVNUQAD0RiHkQACkwFfTcC9i4eAEouqrDvLAUamJjcRCxYXAxQDp5eTW0JAF5N0GRQAH4o2LX9LFwdUHN9RUP40CJ4MglzAG5a1UtLTJscxAAmB1FnOQqMNmAAhUa+ATCRxiUjBaQscERLATNSrG6JZKIVLpazZOx5BGyUFFEplCog0Go1QNJotVqDeGhMEQyLRSaqYiQDBkFGQYwAKyaWB26wMiAA7pUiWwGS8OZzubzFmRPABrUBi-lC4gi3i05o4VqKdESXTIcz9F6vSbTWbzFXqm3vDJcnko6AyqlijCS6XM0Fy4pKlHTMgIFFiz0B-WNQ1tK3BnlY3jwSDMVphiMrOKIK1AA).

Now, the question is how to do it in Rust.
I know I can use tuples:

```rust
// module1/interfaces/do_thing_a_input.rs
type IDoThingAInput = (i8,);
// module1/interfaces/do_thing_a_output.rs
type IDoThingAOutput = (bool,);

// module1/do_thing_a.rs
struct DoThingA;

impl DoThingA {
  pub fn execute(&self, input: IDoThingAInput) -> IDoThingAOutput {
    match input {
      (1,) => return (true,),
      _ => return (false,),
    }
  }
}

// module2/interfaces/do_thing_b_output.rs
type IDoThingBOutput = (bool,);

// module2/do_thing_b.rs
struct DoThingB;

impl DoThingB {
  pub fn execute(&self) -> IDoThingBOutput {
    let do_thing_a = DoThingA {};
    let result = do_thing_a.execute((1,));

    return result;
  }
}

fn main() {
  let do_thing_b = DoThingB {};
  let result = do_thing_b.execute();
  println!("{:#?}", result.0);
}
```

Here the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d5ead0352d1bfa52534c10a76197cb3a).

But this is very inconvenient, as I can miss or confuse values in tuples easily: I like to have key/value pairs to see the name of the value I'm passing, which avoids confusions.

Which options do I have in Rust to define my «interfaces» as key/value pairs?

EDIT: take in account that modules should not mention each other to avoid coupling them.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just use a struct?

Comment: Because input and output are just data. That would be as using classes instead of interfaces in TypeScript; which will work, but classes are meant for holding values and the logic regarding those values. There is a second reason though: AFAIK, Rust struct has an identity, so even when struct `A` and `B` have identical fields, their instances `a` and `b` wont comply with the other: a function that accepts a parameter of type `A` will return error when passing `b`. Of course you can import `B`and instantiate it, but you would couple all modules and create a nice spagetti.

Comment: That sounds like you are trying to do structural typing in a type system that fundamentally doesn't support it. The closest you are going to get is to have a private struct, a trait with methods to get/set the fields, and then pass around trait object references. But probably the best thing to do is stop trying to force structural typing patterns on a typesystem that has alternative ways of dealing with this. In rust it is considered normal to couple the raw data types.

Comment: If you don't want to couple the modules, the standard way to deal with that would be to define the types in a third module, and then have logic modules all depend on that data module.

Comment: In Rust, a struct is the primary product type. If you want multiple values in a single type, you probably want a struct. They are not classes, and so idiomatic Rust as a language doesn't have the idea that structs shouldn't be used for data that doesn't have associated logic. There is no reason to bring this concept from another language with a very different typesystem into Rust.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed response. It seems that Rust has both structural and nominative type systems: structural for tuples and nominative for structs. What I'm looking for is a key/value pairs structure that supports structural typing; but it seems that in Rust this doesn't exist.

Comment: This opens the question about architecture: how to develop modules with contracts stored within the modules describing how to interact with it. Kind of a vendor machine that has a stick in the front describing how to interact with it, and the actual input —coins— as well as the output —cola can—. But this will be a new question.